# How to *NOT* turn taskbar button into task when clicked?

Tags: windows-10

Here you can see I have Edge pinned to my taskbar, and it's open, so now it's wide; clicking on it again will switch to the Edge window.

[image]

I want those taskbar buttons to stay as buttons, not be replaced by the window. Is there a setting for that, or 3rd party tool?

Comment: Does the Always hide labels option in the combine taskbar buttons setting in the Taskbar Settings do what you want?

Comment: @DavidMarshall No, it does not. I like seeing the full text/window title. Even if I liked that, the placement is still wrong. The Edge button should always open a new Edge window, not the existing program.

Answer (score 1):

Create a shortcut with the target: **`cmd /c MicrosoftEdge.exe`** and pin it to your *Taskbar*.

Not sure how to assign the official icon yet. Will investigate

Answer (score 0):

There is a Taskbar Setting called *Combine Taskbar Buttons* which you can set to *Always, hide labels*. In this case, it will stay as an icon but the background will change when there is at least one instance running to let you know. The button will no longer expand and show the title of the window.

Comment: I like the expanding. I don't like the instance running indicator. I want my running apps ungrouped from the launchers.